# VS Code - broken auto check of links for Django/Python

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

This is not a good question, but I used to have in Django/Python files in VS Code automatic check by yellow colour, that model, variable, view, function etc. are correctly somewhere defined and I can use them. But something broke and everything is now white.

Does anybody know, where to switch on again this check for Python/Django? HTML and JavaScript files are working fine, but for Python files it was broken.

[image]

Comment: This may be related to some extensions you installed. They conflict. I think the easiest way is to reinstall vscode.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, I unistalled Django and Python and installed them back and it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was related to some extensions you installed which were conflict with each other.

I think the easiest way is to **reinstall** vscode.